# Checking whether the service is down

Tags: javascript

```
var Model = function() {

       function checkStatus(){

          JsonClient.onload = function() {

          };

          JsonClient.onerror = function(e) {

          };

       }

}
```

I know the error handler would be called when my request parameter is wrong or may be even if the service is down too.

But is there any way i can check my service is down at first place before sending the data.

Comment: How useful that information could be? You send the test request, a moment after the service is down, then you send your real request and what's next?

Comment: I agree with zerkms here. Sending the data is really your test to see if the server is up. Maybe you could explain a bit more, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @zerkms: One use-case would be to send test requests periodically *after* the service goes down, to see (and inform the user) when it is back up again.

Comment: @Thilo: But that could be costly right...

Comment: @JohnCooper Yes. That's why people are asking why you need to do it in the first place.

Comment: @Juhana: I was asking because some of request object is very huge and i don't want memory to be consumed unnecessarily.

Comment: @JohnCooper -- I'd be surprised if your object was 'huge' enough to really matter on modern machines (Even megs of data isn't that much, really.).  Depending on how often you retry, you /could/ drop the object off in `localStorage`

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher: If you are developing for Mobile Application, then Memory does matter a lot.